# Yocto/Bitbake recipe for adding empty directory to rootfs Embedded Linux

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

Is there any recipe for adding a new, empty directory to the rootfs? I tried adding this into one of my bbappend file:

```
do_install() {
   install -d ${D}/tmp/myNewDir
}
FILES_${PN} += "/tmp/myNewDir"
```

but I am getting a non descriptive error, `Function failed: do_install`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways. The image command way is already described by StackedUser.

You can also try to extend some of your recipes (as you are doing in your question). I guess that you are seeing the error because you are overwriting the `do_install` task. You are probably wanting to extend it, so you should add `_append` to the task name, i.e.:

```
do_install_append () {
   install -d ${D}/tmp/myNewDir
}
```

BTW, the error "Function failed: do_install" you are hitting usually show an error code or a problematic command. Maybe there is something.

Another way is to create a simple recipe and add it to the image, here is a stub:

```
SUMMARY = "XXX project directory structure"
# FIXME - add proper license below
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
PV = "1.0"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit allarch

do_install () {
        install -d ${D}/foo/bar
}

FILES_${PN} = "/foo/bar"
```

Answer (score 3):

In our image recipe we have something like this to create a new directory:

```
create_data_dir() {
   mkdir -p ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/data
}

IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND += "create_data_dir;"
```