# Bitbake add empty folder to root

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I want to create a folder in `/home/root` during my bitbake build. I have tried two different methods, both of which fail.

The first gives a huge error that I cannot scroll to the top of

```
do_install_append () {
   install -d ${D}/root/smg_logs
}
```

The second will build and run, but I do not see the created folder.

```
create_dirs() {
    mkdir -p root/smg_logs
}

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "create_dirs ; "
```

If I try the previous with the following

```
create_dirs() {
    install -d ${D}/home/root/smg_logs
    mkdir -p /home/root/smg_logs
}

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "create_dirs ; "
```

This allowed my device to boot but it seems that it has overwritten some important code.

Edit: Similar to the links in the answer below, I have tried the following.

```
do_install_append () {
   install -d ${D}/root/smg_logs
}
FILES_${PN} += "/root/smg_logs"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same question mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653297/yocto-bitbake-recipe-for-adding-empty-directory-to-rootfs-embedded-linux) and [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2015-September/026632.html)

For the `do_install_append` method, do not forget to add the folder to the package:

```
FILES_${PN} += "/root/smg_logs"
```

`/root/smg_logs` or `/home/root/smg_logs` ?

Comment: I have seen these answers before and I am updating my question